# How to update particular row in sql using the content of particular bootstrap 4 cards?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have the following database:

| fund_name | fund_description | amount_received | actual_amount

Bootstrap With PHP :

```
<div class="card-deck">
        <?php 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fundraiser;";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                            echo '<div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top" >
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h5 class="card-title">'.$row['fund_name'].'</h5>
                            <div class="card-text">

                             <p>'.$row['fund_description'].'</p>

                           <h6>Amount:'.$row['actual_amount'].'</h6>
                            <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
                            style="width:'.$row['amount_received'].'%;"aria- 
                            valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria- 
                            valuemax="1000">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <div class="mt-2">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" data- 
             toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"> Donate 
                </button>
                </div>


                                                 </div>

                                            </div>

                                         </div>';
                                }


                             ?>

                        </div>
                        <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" 
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria- 
    hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal 
            title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
           label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Enter Amount</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" 
        placeholder="Enter Amount">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-small" 
         id="formGroupExampleInput" >
        </div>

                                    </form>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Here In my above code im obtaining data from database and displaying the fundraisers using the bootstrap 4. Each fundraisers is displayed using the cards and each card has a donate button. Donate button links to a modal which has a form to pay amount to fundraisers.

My Question is how to differentiate the donate button of a particular card that payment is going on for that so that i can store 'amount_received' field in database for a particular row of fundraiser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-id` to store the id of each fundraiser. When a user click on the button to open the modal, you will get the value of data-id. In the modal form I add `<input type="hidden" name="fundid" id="fundid">` to store the data-id. Try the following code:

Here is a replicate of your data in php array:

```
<?php 
$fundraiser = array( 
    array('id'=>1,'fundname'=>"Anyname","description"=>"About fund","actual_amount"=>50.00,'amount_receive'=>40),
    array('id'=>2,'fundname'=>"Anyname2","description"=>"About fund3","actual_amount"=>100.00,'amount_receive'=>90),
    array('id'=>3,'fundname'=>"Anyname3","description"=>"About fund3","actual_amount"=>20.00,'amount_receive'=>10)
);
?>
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
        <?php 
    foreach($fundraiser as $key=>$val):
          echo '<div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" >
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title">'.$val['fundname'].'</h5>
                       <div class="card-text">
                          <p>'.$val['description'].'</p>
                           <h6>Amount:'.$val['actual_amount'].'</h6>
                           <div class="progress">
                               <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
                            style="width:'.$val['amount_receive'].'%;"aria- 
                            valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria- 
                            valuemax="1000">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          <div class="mt-2">
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary fundid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-id="'.$val['id'].'"> Donate 
                             </button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
             </div>
        </div>';
      endforeach; ?>
</div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>              
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action='updatedb.php'>
        <div class="modal-body">            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Enter Amount</label>
                        <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Enter Amount">
                </div>    
                <input type="hidden" name="fundid" id="fundid">                      
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-small" id="formGroupExampleInput">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To get data-id and store in the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.fundid').on('click', function (e) {
       $('#fundid').val($(this).attr("data-id"));       
    });
```

We don't want to leave trace of the data-id when we close the modal dialog

```
    $('#exampleModalCenter').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#fundid').val('');
    });
</script>
```

When you submit the form, it will submit the data to updatedb.php. In updatedb.php, to get the form data:

the content of updatedb.php

```
 <?php
 $fundid = $_POST['fundid'];
 $amount = $_POST['amount'];
 echo "ID=>".$fundid."<br> Amount=>".$amount;
 ?>
```

Comment: I have one more doubt, is this data-id assigned to the modal when we submit the form in the modal. because the data has to go to particular row in sql.

Comment: Why don't you try it youself? Then if it does not work, you can share here with error...

Comment: I am getting this error ' Cannot read property 'val' of undefined'. i am echoing the cards from php. and when i am pressing the button following error shows up. I have defined data-id but it is showing the error.

Comment: actually i have changed this in my script, '$('#fundid').attr('name').val($(this).attr("data-id"));',remaining everything is same in my php. I am trying to assign data-id value to name of fund-id element.

Comment: Are using ajax to submit the form?

Comment: on what line i cant find

Comment: I have one more doubt. how can we assign the data-id attribute value to name value of modal submit button so that i can use the name in php for running backend code.

Comment: I have added the php code as well, copy the code as it is shown above. It will work.

Comment: can we use ids in $_POST method?? Thats what im thinking for longtime.

Comment: See the form method="POST", so you can use $_POST['fundid'] and $_POST['amount']

Comment: I get it. But u are assign the data-id value to id="fundid". However using name = 'fundid' without assignig it a value in $_POST

Comment: We get the value of the form data from the name attribute. So if you copy the code exactly as I wrote them here, you would surely get the fundid and the amount. If my answer help you, you can click the accept icon (the gray tick icon). When you click, it will become green.

Comment: Thank u so much it helped